# Hide item using CSS

Tags: css

What's wrong with my CSS code? I want to hide the Timestamp column but it's not working? I do not have access to anything in the body, as it is automatically generated, hence i'm trying to use css.

http://snipt.org/Asge0

Code:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-EQUIV="refresh" content="5">

<style TYPE="text/css">
th, td {
padding-RIGHT: 50px;
text-ALIGN: CENTER;
}

.tb  {
CLEAR: both;
}

.tsp {
display: none;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div CLASS="tb"><!--  channeltable schedule="" --><table class="jdt" cellspacing="0">
<colgroup>
    <col CLASS="sid"/>
    <col CLASS="sun"/>
    <col CLASS="chv"/>
    <col CLASS="dfu"/>
    <col CLASS="tsp"/>
</colgroup>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Schedule</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Units</th>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Stream Level</td>
        <td>---</td>
        <td>metres</td>
        <td>2013/06/18  18:10:01.948</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Stream Flow</td>
        <td>---</td>
        <td>cumecs</td>
        <td>2013/06/18  18:10:01.989</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Tank Pressure</td>
        <td>---</td>
        <td>PSI</td>
        <td>2013/06/18  18:10:02.029</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Bubbler Voltage</td>
        <td>---</td>
        <td>V</td>
        <td>2013/06/18  18:10:02.068</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Water Temperature</td>
        <td>---</td>
        <td>Deg</td>
        <td>2013/06/18  18:10:03.176</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Conductivity</td>
        <td>---</td>
        <td>uS/cm</td>
        <td>2013/06/18  18:10:03.244</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Turbidity</td>
        <td>---</td>
        <td>NTU</td>
        <td>2013/06/18  18:10:03.284</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>pH</td>
        <td>OverRange</td>
        <td>pH units</td>
        <td>2013/06/18  18:10:03.322</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Ext. Battery Voltage</td>
        <td>18.996444</td>
        <td>V</td>
        <td>2013/06/18  18:10:03.323</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: You need to set display: none; for row elements <td>

Comment: Can you add javasript? is CSS thru an external file or in the body?

Comment: i can add javascript in the head tags, but i cannot modify anything within the body tags. css has to be in the head tags of the file

Comment: Did you make this work?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**
Try this javascript hack:
(as it is it just reads first `<tbody>`, if you have more than  one in each page you can add another for loop like in `myrows`)

```
var tbody = [];
var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
var myrows = [];
var myrows = tbody[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i in myrows) {
var mycells = [];
var mycells = myrows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    var lastcell = mycells[mycells.length - 1];
    lastcell.style.color = "blue";
}
```

**First answer:**

Try with `:last-child`.

Something like
`td:last-child {display:none;}`

Comment: `tr td + td + td + td + td {display:none }` will work in IE8, ugly selector though.

Comment: @user1406186, just updated the answer, the JS had a bug :) Hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set each `<td>` tag which you like to hide to `<td class="tsp">` `colgroup` does not support the display attribute.

supported attributes are:

> align, char, charoff, valign, width and span

some attributes are not supported in HTML5.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_colgroup.asp

Edit: as you mentioned you can not access table body try this to hide the 5th column in table:

```
tr td:nth-child(5), tr th:nth-child(5) {
    display: none;
}
tr td + td + td + td + td {display:none } /*IE 8*/
```

As fallback for older browsers you also can try just to set `width: 0px` for colgroup

Comment: I believe you can't go without javascript in IE7... I use http://selectivizr.com/ for such things...

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the class to all corresponding td's and th's as well

```
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Schedule</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Units</th>
        <th CLASS="tsp">Timestamp</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>Stream Level</td>
        <td>---</td>
        <td>metres</td>
        <td CLASS="tsp">2013/06/18  18:10:01.948</td>
    </tr>
```

...etc

Comment: i cannot modify anything in the body tags, as it is auto generated by the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pseudo class `:nth-child(n)` on your table:

```
.jdt tr th:nth-child(5), .jdt tr td:nth-child(5) {
    display: none;
}
```

This will hide the 5'th `td, th` elements in the table.

For more special selectors see this article:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: @user1406186 Support IE 9 +

Comment: "Unfortunately in the industry i work in everyone still uses IE6" this would be a reason for me to quit the job...